# How can Haskell function guards operate on other values than the functions parameters?

Tags: haskell

On http://lisperati.com/haskell/ht4.html the author shows functions which read polygons from a simple SVG file. I understand most of the code, however I wondered if it is possible to rewrite the function

```
  let readPoint :: String -> Point
      readPoint s | Just [x,y] <- matchRegex (mkRegex "([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+)") s = (read x,read y)
```

in a more understandable form. I found that line a bit baffling since guards should operate on the parameters of the function (in this case "readPoint") but here the guard apparently operates on the result of matchRegex.

So can anyone explain the magic behind this?

And could this be rewritten to a more understandable form?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can think of guards as just syntax sugar for an if statement. The expression in the guard can be *any* valid boolean expression, just like in if-statements. This means you can use any values and functions in scope.

For example, you can rewrite the following:

```
foo x | abc = ...
      | def = ...
      | otherwise = ...
```

as

```
foo x = if abc then ... else if def then ... else ...
```

We can also write this a bit more verbosely with `case` rather than `if`:

```
foo x = case abc of
  True -> ...
  False -> case def of
    True -> ...
    False -> ...
```

After all, `if` itself is just syntax sugar for a case! Writing everything in terms of `case` makes it easier to see how the different features are just syntax sugar for the same thing.

The second expression clearly makes sense even though the conditions reference existing variables (`abc` and `def`) rather than the function parameter `x`; the guards just work the same way.

You example is a little bit more complicated because it uses an extension called ["pattern guards"](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/5.00/set/pattern-guards.html). This means that the guard can be more than just a boolean--it can also attempt to match a pattern. If the pattern matches, the guard succeeds (e.g. that is the same as a guard with `True`); otherwise, the guard fails to match (just like getting `False`).

We could imagine rewriting it as the following:

```
readPoint s | Just [x, y] <- matchRegex (mkRegex "...") s = ...
            | otherwise = ...
```

as

```
readPoint s = case matchRegex (mkRegex "...") s of
                Just [x, y] -> ...
                _ -> ...
```

You can see the parallel between this and the `case` version of normal guards. Pattern guards just extend the desugaring to arbitrary patterns instead of just booleans.

Again, I'm sure you'll agree that it makes sense to allow *any* expression in the `case` statement--there is no reason to limit it to using the function's arguments. The same is true for the guards because they're really just syntax sugar.

Comment: Excellent! It's always good to remind that pretty much everything in Haskell is just syntactic sugar for some case and lambda expressions.

Answer (score 6):

This is called a *pattern guard* - read up about it [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pattern_guard).

It's equivalent to

```
readPoint :: String -> Point
readPoint s = case matchRegex (mkRegex "([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+)") s of
                   Just [x,y] -> (read x,read y)
```

The idea is that you can get rid of annoying nested case statements. Using pattern guards you could do something like

```
readPoint :: String -> Point
readPoint s | Just [x,y] <- matchRegex (mkRegex "([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+)") s = (read x,read y)
            | Just [x] <- matchRegex (mkRegex "([0-9.]+)") s = (read x,0)
            | otherwise = (0,0)
```

to replace the more verbose

```
readPoint :: String -> Point
readPoint s  = case matchRegex (mkRegex "([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+)") s  of 
                    Just [x,y] -> (read x,read y)
                    Nothing -> case matchRegex (mkRegex "([0-9.]+)") s of
                                    Just [x] -> (read x,0)
                                        Nothing -> (0,0)
```